# Cannot SysPrep Windows 10 Enterprise (spring creators update): "A fatal error occurred..."

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

I have been creating our Windows 10 "golden image" from a VM, but since I installed the "Spring Creators update" I now cannot SysPrep it. Typically, this is the process I would follow, using PowerShell to find and remove all APPX packages:

```
#Audit APPX packages
Import-Module Appx
Import-Module Dism
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Format-List -Property PackageFullName | Out-File C:\Temp\AppxJunkToRemove.txt
```

I then edit the "AppxJunkToRemove.txt" file to create my "RemoveAppXPackages.PS1" script:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package <packagefullname1>
Remove-AppxPackage -Package <packagefullname2>
```

Lastly, I would do two other things:

- Disable the NIC in the VM
- Disable the "Tile Data Model" service - tiledatamodelsvc (which is now gone in the SC update, apparently)

SysPrep is Windows 10 is painful, but following these steps worked 100% of the time for me *before* the Spring Creators Update. However, now the error I get is:

> *"System Preparation Tool 3.14
>
>   A fatal error occured while tyring to sysprep the machine."*

This happens during the "Sysprep is working... processing generalize phase Sysprep plugins..." step. Then this error immediately follows:

[image: Sysprep quit Error code 0]

I have verified that C:\Windows\System32\SysPrep\Panther folder does *not* exist before I try the SysPrep. Setuperr.log shows:
**Error 0x0f00a8 SYSPRP WinMain:Hit Failure while processing sysprep generalize internal providers**

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great blog post on TechNet about [Cleaning up apps to keep Windows 10 sysprep happy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2018/04/17/cleaning-up-apps-to-keep-windows-10-sysprep-happy/). The key takeaways from this are:

- "...sysprep will fail when creating a custom Windows 10 image if there are any apps installed during the image creation process that aren’t also provisioned in the OS."
- "Don’t build your images on a VM that has internet access, since there’s no way the Microsoft Store can download any apps when there is no internet connectivity." (Direct Quotes)

If all else fails, compare your checklist with the [detailed comment on this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad2313f0-09df-4f8d-a840-e5e373ec75e9/capturing-an-upgraded-1709-image-is-broken-as-sysprep-fails?forum=mdt).

Comment: Much thanks. I have read several articles on this, but that is a new one. Checking into it...

Comment: I'm stuck at SysPrep "re-arm fail" now. Any ideas?

Comment: Need more details. 

Comment: I cannot get SysPrep to work and at this point I have to give up and start over in a new VM. I've just spent too much time on it. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

you need to activate windows 10 in order to run sysprep on windows 10.

Reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df9c1f49-f374-46c5-b7c7-5b048a2b442e/sysprep-windows-2016-ltsb-failed-with-setupdigetclassdevs-rearm-error?forum=win10itprosetup